# Where can I find a list of all/top instagram account handles and their number of followers?

Tags: data-request, social-media

I am interested in analysing instagram data, particularly some simple text analysis on the user names AKA 'handles' (language, characters, length etc), as well as number of followers for those accounts.

Is there somewhere I can find a list of all instagram account handles and their number of followers?

If not, is there somewhere I can find a list of the top x account handles ranked by followers? (even if x is small relative to the total number of users, it will still be interesting to analyse)

Notes:

- I have a strong preference for a dataset that is already created (rather than a web scraper that would go an do it, but that would also be useful).
- I don't need it to be up to date - it can be a year or two old